# C# Explicity throw an error on Process.Start()

Tags: c#

I'm a C# beginner and I have made a little launcher for a game and to start it, I'm using this button event:

```
private void button5_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("engine.exe", "/load /config debug");
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

As you can see this also uses Application.Exit() to close the launcher when the game starts, because they are separate.

What I want to know is if my method is good to start the game + close launcher and also,

I would like to know how to make a pop up message saying "Engine.exe not found" when I'm clicking the button and engine.exe is missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using WaitForExit() method ? also to find the engine that is not found  you need to do a if(File.Exist(path+engine.exe)){ } if not found then do MessageBox.Show("your custom message");

Comment: @DJKRAZE He wants the launcher to exit.

Comment: Application.Exit() doesn't raises the Form.Closed and Form.Closing events. If you have code in these events, you should call the Form.Close method. Of course, if your launcher is a simple form without particular resources to free at closing time you could go for Application.Exit()

Answer (score 4):

```
try
{
    Process.Start("engine.exe", "/load /config debug");
    Application.Exit();    
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```